# Mongo 3.0.5 - cannot create index on polygon

Tags: mongodb, indexing, geospatial

I created this document in a collection on Mongo 3.0.5

```
db.s.insert( {_id: "Poly1", shape: {type: "Polygon", coordinates: [[ [3,1], [1,2], [5,6], [9,2], [4,3], [3,1] ]] } })
```

I then try to create a 2dshere index on it

```
db.s.createIndex({"shape.coordinates" : "2dsphere"}, {bits:26});
```

which then gives me this error

```
 "errmsg" : "exception: Can't extract geo keys: { _id: \"Poly1\", shape: { type: \"Polygon\", coordinates: [ [ [ 3.0, 1.0 ], [ 1.0, 2.0 ], [ 5.0, 6.0 ], [ 9.0, 2.0 ], [ 4.0, 3.0 ], [ 3.0, 1.0 ] ] ] } }  Point must only contain numeric elements",
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the except from the manual page on [2dsphere indexes](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/2dsphere/) that is relevant here:

> The **2dsphere** index supports data stored as GeoJSON objects and as legacy coordinate pairs (See also 2dsphere Indexed Field Restrictions). For legacy coordinate pairs, the index converts the data to GeoJSON Point. For details on the supported GeoJSON objects, see GeoJSON Objects.

So the two main words in there are *"pair"* when referring to the legacy coordinate structure, of which can be either an array or a set of key values for longitude and latitude. And the other key word is *"Point"*, in which is how a legacy coordinate pair is stored. It is in fact in that form only *ever* a *"Point"* object.

Your data contains a GeoJSON format and a *"Polygon"*, which ultimately means you are indexing in the "wrong place". Use the root of the GeoJSON instead:

```js
db.s.createIndex({"shape" : "2dsphere"});
```

Then the index is created and will work as designed.

Also, I would advise not to play with other settings on the index until you are a bit more familiar with the way they work here. Get some queries up and running, and then change settings and observe the effects.